# need more whitespace in superscript-type citation call-outs in LaTeX

Tags: citing, natbib, superscripts

I am using LaTeX with

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[super, square, comma]{natbib}
```

I want to get the citation call-outs in the form of

```
AA^{1, 6}
```

But right now I am getting

```
AA^{1,6}
```

i.e. without space after the comma. If I add the `space` option while loading `natbib` like this -- `\usepackage[super, square, comma, space]{natbib}` -- then my document can't be compiled.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your write-up isn't entirely clear since the code fragment you've posted appears to attempt to load the mutually incompatible `cite` and `natbib` packages. However, since you've also set the `natbib` tag, I will assume that you're really looking for a `natbib`-based solution.

If this assumption is correct, all you need to do is replace

```
\usepackage[super, square, comma]{natbib}
```

with

```
\usepackage[super,square]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{citesep={,\kern1.5pt}}
```

Feel free to adjust the amount of kerning to meet your aesthetic preferences.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{A,author="A",title="{AAA}",year=3001}
@misc{B,author="B",title="{BBB}",year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[super,square]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{citesep={,\kern1.5pt}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
AA\cite{A,B}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me it's work. Thanks a lot 

Comment: I did it  as it solved my problem in good way.